# use variables defined in parent php in php coming from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a project in which a user can see his profile on login...but I want the dashboard to load all other profile pages via ajax (i.e. the view profile, edit profile, etc).

So far I have made a `home.php` page that sends an ajax request to `load-page.php`.  Based on the user request it loads the data and checks the requested page then returns the result back to `home.php`.

home.php

```
<div id="pageContent" class="col-md-9">


  </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      loadPage('#dashbord');
    })
  </script> 

  function loadPage(url)  //the function that loads pages via AJAX
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');    

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');  //show the rotating gif animation
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "load-page.php",
        data: {page:url},  //with the page number as a parameter
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)    //if no errors
            {
              $('#pageContent').html(msg);    //load the returned html into pageContet
              $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');//and hide the rotating gif
        }
    });
```

load-page.php

```
<?php
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page =$_POST['page'];
$page=explode('#', $page);
if(strpos($page[1],'?id=')){
$probstr=$page[1];
$newpage = explode('?', $probstr);
$id=explode('=', $newpage[1]);
$_GET['id'] = $id[1];
echo include ''.$newpage[0].'';
}else{
if(file_exists(''.$page[1].'.php')){
echo include ''.$page[1].'.php';
}
else {echo 'There is no such page!';}
}
?>
```

I want to use variables that will be defined in home.php to use in the pages coming from ajax.  However currently I get an undefined index error thrown.

Comment: Only session variables persist between different scripts. Or you can send the variables as parameters in the AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar how ?? can u please write some code

Comment: Where are you trying to use variables from `home.php` in `load-page.php`? All the variables come from `$_POST['page']`.

Comment: Why do you have `echo` before your `include` statements?

Comment: Read a tutorial about PHP session variables.

Comment: `echo include ''.$page[1].'.php';` This is not going to do what you're wanting it to do (if you are thinking that it will make your home.php include that file). By the time the javascript/ajax runs (client-side), the PHP has already terminated (server-side) and no further PHP commands (including `include` ) will be processed

Comment: @Barmar echo is to send this include statement back to home.php

Comment: can anyone suggest some other method to achive my goal

Comment: If you want to send the include statement, you need to quote it. But it doesn't get sent to home.php, it gets sent as a response to `$.ajax`.

Comment: @mrritunjaypathak It's not clear what your "goal" is. You mention using variables from `home.php` in `load-page.php`. Which variables are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use session variables to pass information from one page to another.

At the beginning of each script put:

```
session_start();
```

In home.php you can then do something like:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

after you get the username.

In `load-page.php` you can do:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

at the beginning and then use this variable in the rest of the script.